# Update of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt causing breaking change in IdentityServer3 Client

Tags: c#, security, identityserver3

Hopefully an easy one to resolve.

Microsoft's `System.IdentityModels.Tokens.Jwt` package was updated yesterday on NuGet from `4.0.2.206211351` to `v5.0`. This is unfortunately causing a breaking change with some "standard" `IdentityServer3` code. i.e. taken from their code samples so I imagine quite a few developers might see this issue over the coming days.

## Original Code

using v4.0.2.xxxxxx version of the package. I have

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

in the namespace.

then in the Configuration method begins as:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "sub";

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        { ... };
```

## After Updating

After updating the confgiuration line:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Is causing an issue.

The first thing being that the Class has, apparently, moved into the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` namespace, this isn't so bad to resolve.

However, I'm now getting an `Object reference required for a non-static field` error on the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap`.

Am I missing something here, another library that's required or is there something happening before the `Startup.Configuration()` is called that needs digging into?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you go to the doctor and say "it always hurts when I do this" - the doctor will reply "then stopping doing this" ;)

v4 -> v5 is by definition a breaking change. Do you need v5?

That being said - a simple intellisense exploration would have brought up that they renamed `InboundClaimTypeMap` to `DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap`.

Be prepared for more breaking changes along the way.

Comment: Many thanks. Ah,... no we're not ready for v5 yet, this was me doing a general update of NuGet packages before starting an unrelated story. I'm going to have to live with those Update Alerts not being cleared for a while. In one sense I'm glad that it's an easy fix; in another I feel a bit daft for asking... But, I suppose that's software development in a nutshell :-)

Comment: Using the latest version (5.X.X) it is now `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap`

Answer (score 1):

Access token validation in OWIN is not compatible with system.identitymodel v5 - you need to downgrade to v4 - [See issue here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/150)

Comment: Please note that this is not true anymore, see https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Migrating-from-Katana-(OWIN)-3.x-to-4.x